# How to make observable class variable @Bindable when it is also used as @Environment?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observable

I have following global observable for a user profile:

```
@Observable class User {
  var username = ""
  var isAdmin = false
}
```

This observable is then set as an environment and accessed from various places like so

```
@Environment(User.self) private var user
```

I'm now trying to figure out how I can use `@Bindable` here in order to have a textfield that could update username, but simply using `$` doesn't seem to work i.e.

```
TextField(text: $user.username)
```

Above throws an error like this `Cannot find '$user' in scope`

Comment: Can't you just make a local variable? `@Bindable var bindableUser = user` and use `$bindableUser`?

Comment: Would that propagate changes "globally" i.e. to observable that was set up as environment variable?

Comment: I haven't tried but it should. It's not a struct. It has reference semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Bindable` can be used with local variables:

In `body`, just do

```
@Bindable var bindableUser = user
```

to make a `Bindable` user. Then you can use `$bindableUser.someProperty` as usual.

Here is a simple example:

```
struct Foo: View {
    @Environment(User.self) var user
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.username)
        Text(user.isAdmin ? "Yes" : "No")
        @Bindable var bindableUser = user
        TextField("Foo", text: $bindableUser.username)
        Toggle("Foo", isOn: $bindableUser.isAdmin)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this works, never used @Bindable inside body this way. Thank you.

Comment: @Ilja This usage is also shown in the documentation page for [`Bindable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bindable).